# Spring Batch picking old values from csv file

Tags: csv, spring-batch

I have Spring Batch application that reads osm-billers.csv file. When I run the application , it is processing the records available in csv file. Then I changed the content of the file and saved it. But, it still reads the old contents. It was reading the file earlier without problem, now giving issue as if there is caching problem. My csv file contains only 3 or 4 records.

BillerOrderId
1001289463281044
1001289073251049
1000819614021112
000000002

```
public class BatchConfiguration  {
  @Autowired
  public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

  @Autowired
  public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  @Autowired
  private CsvFileToDatabaseJobConfig csvFileToDatabaseJobConfig;

  @Autowired
  private DatabaseToCsvFileJobConfig databaseToCsvFileJobConfig;

  @Bean
  public FlatFileItemReader<Biller> reader(){
   try {
      FlatFileItemReader<Biller> itemReader = csvFileToDatabaseJobConfig.csvFileItemReader();     
      return itemReader ;
    } catch (UnexpectedInputException e) {
        throw new OrderBatchException("Invalid Input..." + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new OrderBatchException("Parsing error..." + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NonTransientResourceException e) {
        throw new OrderBatchException("NonTransientReasource error..." + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new OrderBatchException("Unknown Read error..." + e.getMessage());
    }

  }

  @Bean
  public OrderProcessor processor() {
      return new OrderProcessor();
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemWriter<Biller> writer() {
      try {
          ItemWriter<Biller> itemWriter = databaseToCsvFileJobConfig.databaseCsvItemWriter();
          return itemWriter;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new OrderBatchException("Unknown Write error..." + e.getMessage());
      }

  }

  @Bean
  public Job importJobOrder(JobCompletionNotificationListner listener, Step step1) {
      return jobBuilderFactory.get("importJobOrder")
              .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
              .listener(listener)
              .flow(step1)
              .end()
              .build(); 
  }

  @Bean
  public Step step1(ItemWriter<Biller> writer) {
      return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
              .<Biller, Biller> chunk(10)
              .reader((ItemReader<? extends Biller>) reader())
              .processor(processor())
              .writer(writer)
              .build();
  }

}

public class CsvFileToDatabaseJobConfig {
   @Bean
   FlatFileItemReader<Biller> csvFileItemReader() {
       FlatFileItemReader<Biller> csvFileReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
       csvFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("osm-billers.csv"));
       csvFileReader.setLinesToSkip(1);

       LineMapper<Biller> billerLineMapper = createBillerLineMapper();
       csvFileReader.setLineMapper(billerLineMapper);

       return csvFileReader;       
   }

   private LineMapper<Biller> createBillerLineMapper() {
       DefaultLineMapper<Biller> billerLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

       LineTokenizer billerLineTokenizer = createBillerLineTokenizer();
       billerLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(billerLineTokenizer);

       FieldSetMapper<Biller> billerInformationMapper = createBillerInformationMapper();
       billerLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(billerInformationMapper);

       return billerLineMapper;
   }

    private FieldSetMapper<Biller> createBillerInformationMapper() {
       BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Biller> billerInformationMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
       billerInformationMapper.setTargetType(Biller.class);
       return billerInformationMapper;
}

    private LineTokenizer createBillerLineTokenizer() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer billerLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        billerLineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"billerOrderId"});
        return billerLineTokenizer;
    }
}


public class OrderReader implements ItemReader<OrderResponse>{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderReader.class);

    private final String apiUrl;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private OrderResponse orderResponse;

    @Autowired
    private OrderRequest orderRequest;

    private String userName;
    private String password;


    public OrderReader(String apiUrl, String userName, String password, RestTemplate restTemplate, OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.orderRequest = orderRequest;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    private boolean orderisNotInitialized() {
        return this.orderResponse == null;
    }

    private OrderResponse fetchOrderDataFromApi(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
         log.debug("OrderRequest = " + orderRequest.getOrder().getBillerOrderId());
         log.debug("apiUrl = " + apiUrl); 
         log.debug("userName = " + userName);

         HttpHeaders headers  = new HttpHeaders();
         headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
         headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
         headers.setBasicAuth(userName, password);

         HttpEntity<OrderRequest> requestEntity =
                 new HttpEntity<OrderRequest>(orderRequest, headers);

         ResponseEntity<OrderResponse> response = 
                 restTemplate.exchange(apiUrl,HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,OrderResponse.class);

         log.debug("response = " + response);

         OrderResponse orderResponse = response.getBody();
         return orderResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public OrderResponse read()
            throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        if (orderisNotInitialized()) {
            orderResponse = fetchOrderDataFromApi(orderRequest);
        }

        return orderResponse;
    }

}


public class OrderProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Biller, Biller>{

    @Value("${osm.service.url}")
    private String orderUrl; 

    @Value("${osm.service.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${osm.service.password}")
    private String password;

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public Biller process(Biller biller) throws Exception {  
          OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest();
          Order order = new Order();
          order.setBillerOrderId(biller.getBillerOrderId());
          orderRequest.setOrder(order);
          OrderReader osmReader = new OrderReader(orderUrl, userName, password, restTemplate, orderRequest);    
          OrderResponse orderResponse = osmReader.read();

          if (orderResponse.getResult().equals("SUCCESS") ) {
              return null;
          } else {
              //Failed transactions
              return biller;
          } 

    }

}
```

For testing purpose, I made BillerOrderId as 4 digits and picks up immediately but when I change to 16 digits , it takes time to execute updated 16 digit BillerOrderId. It works after 4 or 5 attempts. I tried to see the duration it picks up updated records. But, i didn't see any consistency.

Thanks,
Bandita Pradhan

Comment: How do you run your job? Is the input file a job parameter? I see you use `csvFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("osm-billers.csv"));`, are you sure you clean up /rebuild your project after changing the file content and before re-running the job?

Comment: Right now, I am running from STS itself. Run as -> Java Application. My input files osm-billers,csv is in classpath.

Comment: What I noticed after 5pm when the load in VPN is low, it does not give any problem.